# AR content/ game objects not coupled to the area target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, ar-foundation, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I'm experiencing the following issue. I'm building an AR app with unity 2022.2.10, Vuforia Engine 10.14.4 and the AR Foundation. I'm building to an IOS device and would like to recognize the area target, and only then show the AR content/ gameobjects.
Even though, everything looks fine in my unity editor and simulator view (no error messages), when I bulit it and test it on my Iphone the AR conent shows up wherever I open the app. It seems as the AR content/ gameobjects are not coupled to my area target!

As a next step, I tried to parent the gameobjects/ the AR content to the area target in the hopes it would then show only when the area target is recognized, but this resulted in the gameobjects/ Ar content not showing up at all while I look through my device inside the area target (the physical space)!

Answer (score 0):

On the area target in inspector there are two events, On target found and on target lost , you can toggle the visibility of the AR content based on Target found and lost